# Passing custom variables to the PayPal API/IPN FLASH AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to find a solution to my checkout. It's for a customisation app that I have made, in which users choose a T shirt, design, ink colours, sizes ect. This is a pure as3 flash application, that will eventually be hosted on the brands website. I have API username and cert, and I am currently utilising a Buy Now button, which uses code snippets from paypals HTML button code. 
// These are the code snippetts for the Buy Now button for a White Design1 product.

```
//Listeners
buyTingBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buyTINGnow);

//Functions
function buyTINGnow (event:MouseEvent):void
{
      var url:String = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"; //<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
      var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
      var paypal_buynow:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
      paypal_buynow.cmd="_s-xclick"; //<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
      paypal_buynow.hosted_button_id="000000000000"; //<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="000000000000">
      paypal_buynow.invoice="test";
      request.data = paypal_buynow;
      navigateToURL(request);
      trace(paypal_buynow)
}
```

I also have clothingVars which are vars storing these changes as they happen as text.

```
//Clothes Variables
var clothingType:String = "White";
var gender:String = "Male";
var clothingSize:String = "Small";
var quantity:String = "1";
var design:String = "";
var colour1:String = "";
var colour2:String = "";
```

How can I securely pass these variables to the IPN email I receive or tie them to the order.
I'm really struggling to find a solution and speeding towards my final hand in this week, so any help is grately appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

You could pass these over in the variable "custom" to PayPal.  The variable "custom" is a pass through variable, and is returned to you in IPN.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have managed to find a solution. You can actually pass a multitude of HTML variables to the API in AS3. Where in the code above I was replacing <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="000000000000">
with...
paypal_buynow.hosted_button_id="000000000000";
I am now passing the quantity & item name, which lists all the options from my clothing variables. :) Piece of cake! Thanks!
HTML doc here... https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HF080O3